# Addup identifier not found?

Tags: c++

I have my integer defined, yet still comes up wrong? Addup is at the bottom.

> Error C3861 'Addup': identifier not found.

**code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int AddUp(double input, double sum)
{
    sum += input;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    float sum = 0;
    int val = 0;
    cout << "This is an addition program, enter  to quit" << endl;

    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "Next number: ";
        cin >> val;

        if (val == 0)
        {
            cout << "The sum of those numbers is: " << sum << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            return 0;
        }
        sum = Addup(val, sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you defined `AddUp` and you call `Addup`.
C++ is case sensitive !

And also to improve your program (as precised by M.M in the comment this is not the reason it does not compile) :

When you call  `sum = Addup(val, sum);` in your `main()` :

`val` is an `int` and `sum` is a `float`.
Also your return type is an `int` but you declared `sum` as a float.

**But** your function declaration is :

```
int AddUp(double input, double sum);
```

You need to be coherent about the types ! You are excepting `double` types and you gave it an `int` and a `float` !

So if you change this :

```
double AddUp(double input, double sum)
```

and

```
double sum = 0;
double val = 0;
```

Or if you prefer stick with `float` or `int` and it should be better

Comment: Just changed both to doubles and followed your formatting, but still somehow undefined...

Comment: This is because you defined AddUp and you call Addup. C++ is case sensitive ! I edited my answer.

Comment: np welcome on SO if problem is solved you can check this answer ! (and I m surprised your program works with the right behaviour ;p)

Comment: It is fine to call the function with different types. There is implicit conversion between integers and floating point in C++. The only problem is that the function returns `int` which will lose precision.